# What is the best way to populate Entity from DTO

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, dto

I'm creating an order service, new to RestServices world.

I need to read the order model into a `OrderDTO` and persist in the DB.

For that I have a below method:

```
@PostMapping(produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public ResponseEntity<OrderDTO> createOrder(@Valid @RequestBody OrderDTO orderDTO) {
    Order order = new Order(orderDTO);
    Order createdOrder = orderService.createOrder(order);
    OrderDTO createdOrderDTO = new OrderDTO(order);
    ResponseEntity<OrderDTO> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<OrderDTO>(createdOrderDTO, null, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    return responseEntity;
}
```

Everything working fine, but I have concerns about the current design:

1. I'm reading an input into DTO
2. To Store the object I'm converting into Order object which will be persisted by Hibernate
3. Again to send the response back I'm converting the actual order object into DTO.

finally I will create 4-5 Objects per a request, if my app got 100 request it may run into memory issue.

How i can read the model data and persist efficiently?

Comment: You won't run into any memory issue by creating 4-5 short-lived objects per request. And 100 requests is absolutely nothing.

Comment: Okay, Thank you for your  time, Is there any way to implement this in a better way?

Comment: I wouldn't couple the JPA entities to DTOs. I wouldn't wrap the result into a ResponseEntity. And I would use a different DTO to represent what the user submits to create a new order, and what you choose to return to describe the order.

Comment: I'd highlight separating DTOs from business objects. They shouldn't know about each other. By making them aware of one another you're coupling the presentation (DTOs) and service/business layer (in your snippet it's even bidirectional), which almost always is a design flaw.

Note that there are tools that can generate mapping utils between DTOs and business obljects automatically.

Comment: as suggested by @jannis you can use MapStruct to automatically generate mappers between DTOs and Entities. For the design, I think you are doing fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, prefer DTO because of `single responsibility principle`, every object have its own responsibility and It's also clearer to separate View/Controller from Model objects

You can sometimes reduce `OrderDTO`, use an object that is both DTD and real Object,

It'll include DTD properties and also other properties that you can add using builder for example, I'm using `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to set only the DTD properties when object is created from request, e.g.:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class Order
```

You can also use [JsonGetter/JsonProperty/JsonSetter](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/misc/jackson/renaming-properties.html) to control what expected/returned

> @JsonGetter and @JsonSetter are old alternatives to @JsonProperty.

Comment: Thank you for your time for en lighting me on this. I have a doubt then why people prefer to use DTOs?

Comment: @Abdul usually people prefer DTO because `single responsibility principle`, every object have its own responsibility. It's also clearer to separate it

Answer (score 1):

I prefer a Mapper like Mapstruct:

```
OrderDtoMapper mapper = new OrderDTOMapper();

Order order = OrderDtoMapper.map(orderDto, Order.class);
```

and back:

```
OrderDTO createdOrderDTO = OrderDtoMapper.map(order, OrderDTO.class);
```

For me the code looks more readable ... and you do not have much to write for, as Mapstruct maps it automatically. Because it looks like you will map quite a lot ;)
Perhaps a mapper is worth a try: http://mapstruct.org/

Comment: Oh performance ... i would say the performance is not so bad ...https://www.baeldung.com/java-performance-mapping-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with the design.

As Nizet pointed out. Objects created are short lived.

Normally DTO and Entity design is followed to keep the UI and Service Layer separate.

In this way, you have the option to filter out sensitive info from being passed to the world like password, pin.

But if you want you can use `Order` entity directly in Controller class.

I won't suggest that but it's possible.